# django oscar order change page keeps loading. getting 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: django, nginx, kibana, gunicorn, django-oscar

I am getting 502 Bad Gateway. I am using a django oscar application. its running on docker. i also have nginx configured in a container. **All the other pages work**, except order change page. http://localhost:888/admin/order/order/60/change/
When i looked into gunicorn logs, it is showing [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT. Maybe a memory leak or an infinite loop? But i dont see any stack trace, or where it is getting this error. How do i debug this? Its a faily large application. I did increase the gunicorn timeout. didnt help.
Any help is appreciated.

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      dockerfile: local.Dockerfile
      context: ./src
    working_dir: /opt/supplyme_core
    command: |
      sh -c "
      while ! timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/db/5432'; do sleep 1; done
      while ! timeout 1 bash -c 'cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/e_search/9200'; do sleep 1; done
      python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
      /usr/local/bin/gunicorn project.wsgi:application --timeout 300 -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:888 & \
      python service_runner.py api.web.service -c /opt/supplyme_core/api/conf/local_config.yml"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:2220:22"
    volumes:
        - ./src/supplyme_core:/opt/supplyme_core
        - ./.pycharm_helpers:/root/.pycharm_helpers
        - public:/opt/public
        - ./src/scripts/local/freeze.py:/opt/freeze.py:ro
        - ./.ssh:/root/.ssh

  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./pg/x64
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:5432:5432"

  e_search:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
    expose:
      - "9200"

  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.14.1
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://e_search:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://e_search:9200

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.8-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
      - redis-server
      - --bind
      - 0.0.0.0
      - --port
      - "6379"
      - --maxmemory
      - "64mb"
      - --tcp-keepalive
      - "0"
      - --protected-mode
      - "no"
    hostname: redis

  ng:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: ./nginx/local
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/local/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/local/.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd:ro
      - public:/opt/public
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:880:880"
      - "0.0.0.0:888:888"
      - "0.0.0.0:3000:3000"
      - "0.0.0.0:5601:5601"

volumes:
  public:
```